# change element position in linkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I know we can change element position by creating new node and play with node references. How can i change element position **without creating or deleting node, only by play with node references?** many thanks!

```
    public class LinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Iterable<E>
    {
        private Node head; // reference to the first node
        private int N;     // number of elements stored in the list

        private class Node
        {

            public E item;
            public Node next;

            public Node()
            {
                item = null;  next = null;
            }
            public Node(E e, Node ptr)
            {
                item = e;  next = ptr;
            }
        }

    public boolean Move(E e){
        Node current=head;
        while(current !=null){
            if(e.equals(current.item)){
                System.out.println("True");
                return true;
*****Then how to move this node to the front? Without creating and deleting nodes******
            }
            current=current.next;
        }
        System.out.println("False");
        return false;
```

Comment: Where you need to move the node?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I'm trying to write a method that take k-index and move to the front of the linkedList. thanks!

Comment: So what did you come up yourself so far?

Comment: Add the nodes to a new `LinkedList` in the relevant order?

Comment: Just showed my code, please have a look, appreciate it !

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup hi sorry wat do u mean by relevant order, sorry im new to programming

Comment: @John 1) find node `n` in k-th position by iteration, remembering previous node `p`; 2) `p.next = n.next`, `n.next = head`, `head = n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your algorithm should be something like this

```
int count = 1;   // change to 0 if zero-indexed
Node p = null;   // previous
Node n = head;   // current

while(count < k) {
    if(n.next != null) {
        p = n;
        n = n.next;
        count++;
    } else
        break;
}

if(count == k){
    p.next = n.next;
    n.next = head;
    head = n;
}
```

Comment: thanks Vihar! sorry i dont have enough rep to vote u up

Answer (score 0):

```
public void changeOrder(){     
    //keep the pointer to next element of the first
    ListNode current=front.next;
    //make first point to the next element
    first.next=current.next;
    current.next=first;
    first=current;
    //the current one was moved one step back and it points to first.
    //change the position
    current=current.next;
    while(current.next!=null && current.next.next!=null){
        ListNode temp = current.next.next;
        current.next.next=temp.next;
        temp.next=current.next;
        current.next=temp;
        current=temp.next;
    }
}
```